# CakePHP Spark_plug error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User::authsomeLogin() is not implemented!'

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am using spark_plug in my cakephp project and I am having this error when I view my app from a guest account:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User::authsomeLogin() is not implemented!'
```

The website works fine when I am logged in, and I have tried a lot, but still have no idea what's going wrong. Can somebody help me with this? I will be thankful.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this issue too. I found that the problem stems from associating the plugin User model with a separate model in your app without specifying the plugin prefix in the className parameter.

So for instance, I had a belongsTo association in a model in my app that looked like this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Changing it to this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'SparkPlug.User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry the author never accepted your answer. You helped me out, though.